# Newtonsoft pegar parte do JSON

Tags: c#, newtonsoft

Estou trabalhando com C# e quero pegar parte do `JSON` retornado pela requisição `PostAsync`  e este é o retorno da `REQUEST`:

> `{"meta":{"status":422,"error":true},"error":{"status":1102,"msg":"Invalid email, enter email in the format email@yourprovider.com"}}`

Criei a seguinte classe para verificar se error está com `true` ou `false`, mas não consegui pegar parte do `JSON` e associar à classe.

```
public class Meta
{
    [JsonProperty("meta.status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("meta.error")]
    public bool Error { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse tipo de informação que está no formato `JSON` para extrair a informação com o pacote que está anexado a sua pergunta precisa ter um conjunto de classes, seguindo o exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public bool error { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

***Código***

```
var json = "{ ... }";
var result = Newtonsoft
            .Json
            .JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

---

```
result.meta.status // status
result.meta.error // error
```

Você também pode decorar o objeto igual você fez, mas, é cada item na configuração deve ser respeitado.

Comment: Grato @Virgilio Novic, testei e funcionou